# JS, doubling the element of an array and check if the next element of the current element that is doubling is equal to the previous element

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I need help to solve this exercise:
An array is given and composed of
whole numbers. Write a function which takes it
as a parameter this array and modifies it by doubling the values. If the previous value and
next value of the current value that is doubling are
equal, change the value of the next element to
0. In other words :
doubling the element of an array and check if the next element(not doublet yet) of the current element that is doubling is equal to the previous element and if so change the next element to 0.
The given array is:
[0, 2, 5, 4, 1, 0, 3, 3, 6, 7];

```
const nums = [0, 2, 5, 4, 10, 3, 3, 6, 7];

const double = function (arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] *= 2;
    console.log(arr[i]);
    if ((arr[i - 1] = arr[i + 1])) {
      arr[i + 1] = 0;
    }
  }
  return arr;
};
console.log(double(nums));
```

Comment: do you have a result as well?

Comment: the result should be like this i think: const nums = [0, 4, 10, 0, 0, 6, 6, 0, 14];

Answer (score 2):

You could store the preceding value and check if it is equal to the actual element, then store zero or the doubled value.

```js
const
    double = array => {
        let preceding;
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            const value = array[i] * 2;
            array[i] = preceding === array[i] ? 0 : value;
            preceding = value;
        }
        return array;
    };

console.log(...double([0, 2, 5, 4, 1, 0, 3, 3, 6, 7]));
```

Comment: i edited the question, check it out if it is more clear to you?